# Why autohotkey deos not send Ctrl-Space where Space is an input

Tags: autohotkey

Consider the following assignment:
When I type `-` followed by a `key`, the result is `Ctrl-key`. This work for ordinary keys.
But when the key is whitespace, it does not work.

Any idea why this happens?  And how to fix the code?

```
-::
Input, key, L1,{LCtrl}
send, ^{%key%}
return
```

**Edit.**
Try to run the above script a program which has Ctrl-Space as a shortcut to see that it does not work. In fact, if you press `-` followed by `Space`, the script is suppose to call `Ctrl-Space` but it is not the case. For example:

- In Microsoft Excel or in Libreoffice Calc, Ctrl-Space can select the current column.
- In Emacs Ctrl-Space is reserved for setting a Mark.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this error with the `Space`, `Tab`, or `Enter` keys, but from the `Input` [docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm): "**Whitespace characters** such as Tab (\`t) are stored literally. Enter is stored as linefeed (\`n)." Could you possibly give us specific examples of keys that do not function correctly?

Comment: @Spyre I added some explanations to replicate the error.

Comment: Space is one of the default terminator characters, just like Tab, Enter, etc. Change de default to not include space.

Comment: @RobertIlbrink, Does not work even if I specify `Endkeys`. For example I modified the code in order that `LCtrl` is the only `Endkey`, but it does not work either. See the modified code above.

Comment: You are right. I tried your script with the verification line: MsgBox,,,"%key%" just before the send line. This confirms that the space is being read and stored in the key parameter. So the problem is in the send line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SendInput` instead.

Tested in Excel to mimic ^a, ^x, ^v, ^space

```
-::
Input, key, L1,{LCtrl}
SendInput, ^%key%
Return
```

If you want to handle "special" keys, add those keys to the list of endkeys using this syntax

`Input [, OutputVar, Options, EndKeys, MatchList]`

And then check to see which endkey was pressed

Tested in Firefox to mimic ^PgDn, ^PgUp

```
Input, key, L1,{LCtrl}{PgUp}{PgDn}
If (ErrorLevel = "EndKey:PgUp") {
  SendInput ^{PgUp}
}
Else If (ErrorLevel = "EndKey:PgDn") {
  SendInput ^{PgDn}
}
Else If (ErrorLevel = "EndKey:LCtrl") {
  Return   ;assumed you just want to abort input with the control key
}
Else {
  SendInput, ^%key%
}
Return
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves the problem with SPACE, but there are still some problems with other keys. For example when you press `-` followed by `PgUp` or `PgDn`, it is expected that the above command send `Ctrl-PgUp` or `Ctrl-Pgdn`. But it is not the case. For example try to do it in Firefox with several open tabs. In this situation `Ctrl-PgUp` or `Ctrl-Pgdn` are to navigate tabs to the left and right but the above command does not work. Thank you again.

Comment: @Name, I edited the response by adding an alternate solution using endkeys to detect special presses and respond accordingly. Please accept this answer if it works for you.